# Equation too long -> label appears in next line

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath, labels

I have the following long equation and I want to label it but unfortunetly it appears to be too long so the label appears in next line. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{my_eq}
\min_{f,u} \frac{1}{2} \|A(Bu -f)\|^2_2 + \lambda_1\|Cf\|_{1,p} + \lambda_2\|Du\|_{1,p} + 
\frac{\kappa}{2}\|Ef - f_0\|^2_2 + \frac{1}{2}\|E(Pu) - f_0\|^2_2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: long_equation]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are more options: one it is to use `multline` or `split` or to use `geometry` package or of the other strategies.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}\label{my_eq}
\min_{f,u} \mfrac{1}{2} \|A(Bu -f)\|^2_2 + \lambda_1\|Cf\|_{1,p} + \lambda_2\|Du\|_{1,p}\\
+\mfrac{\kappa}{2}\|Ef - f_0\|^2_2 + \mfrac{1}{2}\|E(Pu) - f_0\|^2_2
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `geometry` package you can choose the margins of the paper.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{my_eq}
\min_{f,u} \mfrac{1}{2} \|A(Bu -f)\|^2_2 + \lambda_1\|Cf\|_{1,p} + \lambda_2\|Du\|_{1,p} + \mfrac{\kappa}{2}\|Ef - f_0\|^2_2 + \mfrac{1}{2}\|E(Pu) - f_0\|^2_2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I 'd add a `{}`  after the  + at the end of the first line, for spacing reasons

Comment: @Bernard Done! Approved your comment.

Comment: Maybe, also, the fraction coefficients  would look nicer with medium-sized factions (`\mfrac` from `nccmath`). LaTeX makes me a bit fussy at times :-)

Comment: @Bernard Don't worry. I provide now to edit.

Comment: The `+` sign should go to the next line.

Comment: @egreg You're right...I'm accustomed (abituato) to putting the + at both the end and the beginning :-(